# League of Legends - PlayOnLinux stuck

Tags: 16.04, games, playonlinux

I'm new here. I tried to install League Of Legends game via PlayOnLinux, but after choosing LOL from list of games and clicking **next** I see no progress, just loading all the time.

[image: game stuck screenshot]

Can anyone help me?

I tried also to install with .exe file and got many errors like thisone in the image bellow.

[image: league of legends playonlinux error]

I run Ubuntu 16.04 LTS x64.

Comment: It may be loading. I've experienced long loading times when installed the dotnet components.

Comment: open PlayOnLinux from terminal and check if it outputs any warning or error. Maybe someone can take a look at it here and solve it for you.

Comment: Can you tell me how to do it? I'm not so good with linux :P

Comment: Ok, I found a solution how to install LOL but after pressing in POL "Run" comming BugSplat...
Here is link for tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WMfZ0ycgQbc

Comment: There is a post in r/Ubuntu at https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/51etd2/league_of_legends_on_ubuntu_pol_and_wine_1604_and/ that talks about installing LOL in POL. See if that helps.

Comment: @AndrzejKraszewski what GPU are you using and what driver for the GPU are you using?  Also what is your computer make & model? Can you add this information into your question by editing it?Thanks.

Comment: @edwinksl If you want to post that as an answer, I'll award the bounty. It seems to be working just fine for me. I'll be sure in a little while once the game downloads, but it installed just fine!

Comment: @RPiAwesomeness I am concerned about that "pre-made" script that one has to download and execute. Did you have to run that script? I want to make sure it is safe.

Comment: @edwinksl I did have to run it, but looking it over there doesn't seem to be anything dangerous.

Comment: @RPiAwesomeness Awesome, I also read through it but I wanted a second opinion. Thanks. :)

Comment: @RPiAwesomeness I have written an answer. Please feel free to edit it if you find anything amiss.

Answer (score 9):

There is a [r/Ubuntu post](https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/51etd2/league_of_legends_on_ubuntu_pol_and_wine_1604_and/) in Reddit by [jmobastos69](https://www.reddit.com/user/jmobastos69) that details how to install League of Legends (LOL) in PlayOnLinux (POL). This answer is a cleaner and slightly modified version of that post.

1. Remove `wine` and `playonlinux` and their dependencies that you have installed previously and remove retrieved package files:

   ```
   sudo apt purge wine playonlinux
   sudo apt autoremove
   sudo apt autoclean
   ```
2. Clean install the staging branch of `winehq`  and `wine` for the 32-bit architecture using Wine's [installation instructions](https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu) for Ubuntu:

   ```
   sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:wine/wine-builds
   sudo apt update
   sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-staging
   sudo apt install wine:i386
   ```
3. Install `playonlinux`:

   ```
   sudo apt install playonlinux
   ```
4. Start `playonlinux` as a background process in the terminal:

   ```
   playonlinux &
   ```
5. Save the following script with a name of your choice (note that I copied and pasted the script from jmobastos69's [link](http://www.filedropper.com/install) to this answer so that the script can be audited by everyone here):

   ```
   # Date : (2012-04-12)
   # Last revision : (2015-05-31 08:27)
   # Distribution used to test : ArchLinux, Debian Sid
   # Author : Quentin PÂRIS, Valentin PERRUSSEL, Pierre ETCHEMAITE
   # Licence : GPLv3
   # WineHQ: http://winebuild.playonlinux.com/wine/wine-patches/LeagueOfLegends2/

   # Changelog
   # (2012-05-11) 22:50 - Quentin PÂRIS
   # - New wine patches for better perfomances
   # (2012-05-11) 23:38 - Quentin PÂRIS
   # - Dirty hack that fixes problems
   # (2012-05-12) 09:45 - Quentin PÂRIS
   # - Patches for osx
   # (2012-05-28) 11:00 - Quentin PÂRIS
   # - Checks for recent version of PoL (InsertBeforeWine is bad supported by 4.0.14)
   # (2013-03-10) 22:51 - Pierre ETCHEMAITE
   # - Use web downloader
   # (2013-04-07) 22:23 - Pierre ETCHEMAITE
   # - Reverted as they somehow broke PMB (not even installed)
   # (2013-04-13) 20:12 - GNU_Raziel
   # - Added POL_Wine_SetVideoDriver function
   # (2013-09-07) 21:17 - Pierre ETCHEMAITE
   # - Fix for newer LoL versions
   # (2014-09-01) 21:17 - Quentin PÂRIS
   # - Fix for newer LoL versions (added d3dx9)
   # (2015-01-09) 00:54 - Pierre ETCHEMAITE
   # - Update Wine to fix missing libgcrypto symlink
   # (2015-02-10) 20:25 = Pierre ETCHEMAITE
   # - Use official standalone installer/patcher
   # (2015-05-31) 08:27 = Pierre ETCHEMAITE
   # - use Wine 1.7.44-LeagueOfLegends2 to fix patcher issue
   # (2016-01-26) 12:55 (UTC) - Jeddunk
   # - upgrade Wine to 1.9.2-LeagueOfLegends5

   [ "$PLAYONLINUX" = "" ] && exit 0
   source "$PLAYONLINUX/lib/sources"

   WINEVERSION="1.9.2-LeagueOfLegends5"

   TITLE="League of Legends"
   PREFIX="LeagueOfLegends"
   SHORTCUT_NAME="League of Legends"

   POL_GetSetupImages "http://files.playonlinux.com/resources/setups/$PREFIX/top.jpg" "http://files.playonlinux.com/resources/setups/$PREFIX/left.jpg" "$TITLE"

   POL_SetupWindow_Init
   POL_RequiredVersion "4.0.18" || POL_Debug_Fatal "$APPLICATION_TITLE 4.0.18 is required to install $TITLE"
   POL_SetupWindow_SetID 1135

   which glxinfo || POL_Debug_Error "$(eval_gettext 'glxinfo is not installed. Please install mesa-utils package')"

   if ! glxinfo | grep -q GL_EXT_texture_compression_s3tc; then
   POL_SetupWindow_message "$(eval_gettext 'Warning! S3TC compression is not available on your system.\n\nIf you have a free driver, you might need to install a proprietary driver \n\nOtherwise, you can enable it by installing libtxc-dxtn0 package, but you might get slower results')"
   POL_Debug_Warning "S3TC not enabled!"
   fi

   POL_Debug_Init

   POL_SetupWindow_presentation "League of Legends" "Riot" "http://www.riotgames.com/" "Quentin PÂRIS, BlondVador" "LeagueOfLegends"

   POL_SetupWindow_InstallMethod "DOWNLOAD,LOCAL"

   if [ "$INSTALL_METHOD" = "LOCAL" ]; then
   cd "$HOME"
   POL_SetupWindow_browse "$(eval_gettext 'Please select the setup file to run.')" "$TITLE" "" "Windows Executables (*.exe)|*.exe;*.EXE"

   if strings "$APP_ANSWER"|grep -q '\(name="Pando Media Booster Downloader"\|Advanced Installer\)'; then
   NOBUGREPORT="TRUE"
   POL_Debug_Fatal "$(eval_gettext 'Cant install using the official downloader, sorry')"
   fi
   FULL_INSTALLER="$APP_ANSWER"
   else # DOWNLOAD
   POL_System_TmpCreate "$PREFIX"

   # http://forums.na.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=1474419
   POL_SetupWindow_menu "$(eval_gettext 'Select installer to download:')" "$TITLE" "$(eval_gettext 'North America')~$(eval_gettext 'Europe West')~$(eval_gettext 'Europe Nordic and East')" "~"
   case "$APP_ANSWER" in
   "$(eval_gettext 'North America')")
   DOWNLOAD_URL="http://l3cdn.riotgames.com/Installer/SingleFileInstall/LeagueOfLegendsBaseNA.exe"
   DOWNLOAD_MD5="9d44b68bd02d7b5426556f64d86bbd16"
   ;;
   "$(eval_gettext 'Europe West')")
   DOWNLOAD_URL="http://l3cdn.riotgames.com/Installer/SingleFileInstall/LeagueOfLegendsBaseEUW.exe"
   DOWNLOAD_MD5="eb5d7b007b6022ee555c0dd9fd71263e"
   ;;
   "$(eval_gettext 'Europe Nordic and East')")
   DOWNLOAD_URL="http://l3cdn.riotgames.com/Installer/SingleFileInstall/LeagueOfLegendsBaseEUNE.exe"
   DOWNLOAD_MD5="f08d7b70776b0989eabb016bae77fdaa"
   ;;
   esac
   DOWNLOAD_FILE="$POL_System_TmpDir/$(basename "$DOWNLOAD_URL")"

   POL_Call POL_Download_retry "$DOWNLOAD_URL" "$DOWNLOAD_FILE" "$DOWNLOAD_MD5" "$TITLE standalone installer"

   FULL_INSTALLER="$DOWNLOAD_FILE"
   fi

   POL_System_SetArch "x86"
   POL_Wine_SelectPrefix "$PREFIX"
   POL_Wine_PrefixCreate "$WINEVERSION"

   POL_Call POL_Install_corefonts
   POL_Call POL_Install_vcrun2005
   POL_Call POL_Install_vcrun2008
   POL_Call POL_Install_d3dx9

   Set_OS "win7"

   POL_SetupWindow_message "$(eval_gettext 'Warning: You must not tick the checkbox "Run $TITLE" when setup is done')" "$TITLE"

   POL_Wine_WaitBefore "$TITLE"
   POL_Wine "$FULL_INSTALLER"

   Set_OS winxp

   # Set Graphic Card informations keys for wine
   POL_Wine_SetVideoDriver

   POL_Call POL_Function_OverrideDLL builtin,native dnsapi
   POL_Shortcut "lol.launcher.admin.exe" "$SHORTCUT_NAME" "$SHORTCUT_NAME.png" "" "Game;RolePlaying;"

   if [ "$INSTALL_METHOD" = "DOWNLOAD" ]; then
   # Free some disk space
   POL_System_TmpDelete
   fi

   if [ "$POL_OS" = "Linux" ]; then
   if [ "$(cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_timestamps)" = "1" ]; then
   FORUM_URL='http://forums.euw.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=2058453'
   POL_SetupWindow_question "$(eval_gettext 'If you get connection errors when attempting to login, try disabling tcp_timestamps in the kernel.')\n$(eval_gettext 'Do you want to read original thread in League of Legends forums?')" "$TITLE"
   [ "$APP_ANSWER" = "TRUE" ] && POL_Browser "${FORUM_URL}"
   fi
   fi

   POL_SetupWindow_Close
   exit 0
   ```
6. Choose "Run a local script" from the "Tools" menu of PlayOnLinux and select the script you have just saved.
7. Follow instructions to install League of Legends. Remember to **uncheck** the "Launch League of Legends" box at the end of the installation wizard.
8. In PlayOnLinux, press "Run" on the League of Legends app.

Comment: Can confirm, this does work as of September 2016. Things will probably change in the future, but I was able to get League installed and running. I will report back in a bit when I get a chance to actually play a game.

Comment: Just played a quick vs AI game and it seems to run fine!

Comment: not working for me. the install process completes but when i go to launch the game, it give me a fatal error message and quit

Comment: @NoahPassalacqua Yeah I am not aware of any installation procedure that is robust. It always breaks eventually....

Comment: @edwinksl I got it to work using Lutris!

Answer (score 4):

For anyone that has had trouble with it installing/running using PlayOnLinux, check out [Lutris](https://lutris.net/).

Everything worked amazingly for me on Ubuntu 17.04

I came across this youtube video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0YW5ulQOaGk

Comment: Way nicer than PlayOnLInux, thank you!  Worked on my first try, in just a few clicks, with no weird bugs or glitches. Much more modern way to play games on linux. It's only in version 0.4, but I bet it'll be as easy as steam soon