# How do I install League of Legends on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: games

I already installed League of Legends but everytime I try to open it, this appears:

[image]

```
Details: Failed to change to directory '/home/dannymoya/.wine/dosdevices/c:/Riot GamesLeague of Legends' (No such file or directory)
```

Comment: If you are willing to start from scratch, see http://askubuntu.com/questions/819291/league-of-legends-playonlinux-stuck.

Answer (score 3):

What work for me as patch 6.22 was changing settings of LoL launcher through PlayonLinux.

1. Install the most recent version of PlayonLinux and install the League of Legends. (Do not start game after installation)
2. Using PlayonLinux access the LoL game settings.
3. In PlayonLinux change the default wine version using the "General" tab.From
   1.9.2 LeagueofLegends5 to the latest stagging version. When i wrote this answer it was "1.9.22stagging" i install both x86 and x64 wine versions. (again this all done through the playonlinux settings)
4. Through playonLinux settings now access the "wine" tab and click on "configure wine" icon. There you will change the default windows version from Windows XP to Windows Vista. (all other don't seem to work at least not on my PC)
5. Now using PlayonLinux start the LoL launcher (the screen will look weird, however, you should be able to see the League of legends logo on the top left, the percentage and download speed bar on  the middle and the settings and minimize icons on the right.
6. This installation takes longer than when using windows.For me using Windows LoL installs in about 2.5 hrs. However, using Ubuntu it took 5 to 6 hours to install. During the installation it might seem like if the installation freezes or your installation stops and your download speed might even reduce to cero for a while but "PLEASE BE PATIENT"
7. Today is November 15, 2016 and i install LoL 6.22 and play.
8. if there is any new patch i would try waiting for the new playonlinux stagging version of wine before removing or changing anything else.