# League of legends Ubuntu Play on linux "wget failed: Server issued an error response"

Tags: wine, games, playonlinux

I am getting the following error when running the installer for League of Legends in PlayOnLinux:

```
Error in POL_System_wget
POL_System_wget failed: Server issued an error response
--2016-10-07 16:54:24-- http://l3cdn.riotgames.com/Installer/SingleFileInstall/LeagueOfLegendsBaseNA.exeResolving l3cdn.riotgames.com (l3cdn.riotgames.com)... 209.197.3.7Connecting to l3cdn.riotgames.com (l3cdn.riotgames.com)|209.197.3.7|:80... connected.HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 403 Forbidden2016-10-07 16:54:24 ERROR 403: Forbidden.
```

I first thought this might be a DNS error but I tried changing that but I still got the same error.

The last thing I tried was [League of Legends - PlayOnLinux Stuck.](https://askubuntu.com/a/822703/215526)

Comment: i found the solution: adding to /etc/hosts did the trick

https://www.playonlinux.com/en/topic-14718-cannot_even_get_to_install_in_league_of_legends.html

Comment: Glad you found a solution, can you mark the question as resolved, please?

Comment: how do i do that i dont see a button?

Comment: Under your question there should be a close button next to edit and delete

Comment: try `ping google.com`  and `'ping l3cdn.riotgames.com`

Answer (score 0):

To add the solution from the @zork312 comment this are the values you want to add in your local resolution file `/etc/hosts` :

```
24.143.193.16 l3cdn.riotgames.com
64.202.189.170 pvp.net
50.57.198.72 support.leagueoflegends.com
66.151.54.140 beta.lol.riotgames.com
216.133.234.23 lq.na1.lol.riotgames.com
216.133.234.22 prod.na1.lol.riotgames.com
216.133.234.21 chat.na1.lol.riotgames.com
216.52.241.153 ll.leagueoflegends.com
23.21.255.17 http://www.leagueoflegends.com
23.21.255.17 leagueoflegends.com
216.133.234.24 store.na1.lol.riotgames.com
216.137.47.27 landing.leagueoflegends.com
72.21.91.29 crl3.digicert.com
205.234.175.175 crl4.digicert.com
199.21.207.10 ocsp.digicert.com
```

Comment: not sure if that is the best solutions. as these can easily change and would require an update of host file

Comment: It's maybe not the best solution I agree, but it's better than not posting it and it actually works.