# League of Legends issue ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: wine, games, playonlinux

Last day I'm trying to get league patched and get it after many changes of wine version.

> Currently I'm on use 1.9.23-staging

Next my step was following the guide because of other issues what i can't find. I decided to install everything from it:

> [League of Legends - PlayOnLinux stuck](https://askubuntu.com/questions/819291/league-of-legends-playonlinux-stuck)

Now I have got that problem, when i click "launch" button nothing just happend except closing launcher window and sending a message to terminal: [Terminal message picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nDydk.jpg)

Sorry for my bad english and I'm new to Ubuntu user

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install PlayOnLinux on Ubuntu 16.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/770687/how-to-install-playonlinux-on-ubuntu-16-04)

Answer (score 0):

This seemed to work for me in 16.04

https://github.com/TheUnnamedDude/pol_league_of_legends