# Problems installing League of Legends in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: wine, games, playonlinux

On a vanilla Ubuntu install i cannot figure out for why this refuses to work. Did the initial setup process through PlayOnLinux, failed, so then I tried the method in this link: [League of Legends - PlayOnLinux stuck](https://askubuntu.com/questions/819291/league-of-legends-playonlinux-stuck) This still yielded no results as the client will update (a DLL error pops up but I let the client update in the background anyway). Clicking "Launch" just closes the client and process altogether.

Comment: I think the latest patch is not working (yet) with play on linux.If you look at this website. https://www.playonlinux.com/en/app-1135-League_Of_Legends.html